# How can I wrap DbContext in a wrapper that will allow unit testing of custom methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have the following situation.  Trying to wrap an adapter around a DB Context for various reasons, with simplified unit testing being one of them.  Slimmed down version of the code as follows:

```
    public interface IDbAdapter
    {
        void SaveChanges(string userId);
    }   

    public interface IDbContext
    {
        IDbAdapter Attempt();
    }

    public class DbAdapter : IDbAdapter
    {
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

        public DbAdapter(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public virtual void SaveChanges(string userId)
        {
            PopulateAuditFields(userId);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public partial class MyEntities: IDBContext
    {
        private IDbAdapter _dbAdapter;

        public virtual IDbAdapter Attempt()
        {
             return _dbAdapter ?? (_dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this));
        } 
     }
```

Now this works.  Code simply performs a `(MyEntities Object).Attempt().SaveChanges(userId)` and the unit tests can simply mock this method entirely. There's a bunch of other methods as well on this adapter, but they are not listed here.

However, I am not sure about having to perform this "redirection" to the wrapper implementation.  Is there a cleaner way to achieve such a wrapper?

Just curious what you would recommend in this situation?  I also don't want to create extension methods on the interface, because this has caused me a rabbit hole in regards to unit testing; I've also tried have an Adapter Factory with a public static Func<> property which I can swap out at testing, but that caused issues when running multiple tests in parallel.

**Edit:**
I failed to mention that the MyEntities is a partial class, extending the auto-generated DbContext that is made via Database-First approach of Entity Framework.  Thus, I can not create a parameterless constructor on the partial class.

Comment: You can simply create a field of type `IDbAdapter` which you return in your `Attemp`-method. Why do you want to set `this` to anything? I can´t see what your problem is.

Comment: Could you please explain why don't you want to create a field in the class and initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks HimBromBeere, I updated the question with that implementation which removed the need to create a new DbAdapter each time the Attempt() method was called, and reworded the question to determine if there's a cleaner way to approach this.  Appreciate your comment.

Comment: Thanks Sergii Zhervzhyk for your comment.  I updated the question to make it more clear, but the MyEntities is a partial class that extended the DbContext generated from EF.